# Long texts with CCLabelBMFont in Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fonts, cocos2d-iphone

What's the best way to display long texts in Cocos2D using the CCLabelBMFont class?

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to solve this problem using the class CCLabelBMFontMultiline, written by Mark Wei. His code is available at:

```
https://github.com/pingpongboss/CCLabelBMFontMultiline
```

Maybe this will help someone else.